# Android Widget Not Showing on Phone (4.3)

Tags: android, widget

My widget is showing in the widget list. I reused some code from a previous project I was working that used widgets. I also searched for some tutorials and tried to change some so of the attributes, but nothing. For some reason, it is not showing.

Manifest File

```
<receiver
    android:icon="@drawable/iconfile"
    android:label="NameofApp"
    android:name="NameofApp">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/widget_provider" />
 </receiver>
```

Here is the provider xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:minHeight="74dp" 
    android:minWidth="74dp" 
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout" 
    android:updatePeriodMillis="100000"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical">
</appwidget-provider>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

```
android:widgetCategory="keyguard|home_screen"
```

In the widget provider xml. I am not sure why it worked, but it does. If anyone has any answers that I would like to know. Thanks